# Fetch certain .html files from web server

Tags: python, urllib2

I would like to fetch certain .html files from a web server. My intention is to fetch .html files from a web site (http://www.thetabworld.com/) that has a word "metallica" on file name. How is that possible using python? I have heard about urllib2 but as a python noob, I don't have a slightest idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have heard about urllib2 but as a
>   python noob,  I don't have a slightest
>   idea how to use it."

well if you don't know how to use urllib2, reading some docs would be a good start.

the following are excellent resources (with examples):

[official python docs for urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)
[urllib2 - the missing manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)
[urllib2 cookbook](http://personalpages.tds.net/~kent37/kk/00010.html)
[PMOTW - urllib2](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/07/pymotw-urllib2.html)

Comment: RTFM is not a very helpful response

Comment: steve, my answer gave 4 useful links to the best resources on urrlib2.. and was accepted by the OP.  so, i would call it a "helpful response".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use urllib2 together with a HTML parser such as `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` in order to extract the links from the retrieved pages in order to crawl the site.